# I get error that You cannot use a Stripe token more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I run my local server using stripe and I got error when I submitted my payment form.

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def create
   //below is the reason I got error for 
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => params[:amount],
      :description => 'Growth Hacking Crash Course',
      :currency    => 'jpy'
    )

    purchase = Purchase.create(email: params[:stripeEmail], card: params[:stripeToken], amount: params[:amount], description: charge.description, currency: charge.currency, customer_id: customer.id, product_id: 1, uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)

    redirect_to purchase

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end


end
```

I don't know why I get that error. I need your help!!!

Comment: Can u please specify what error u are getting?

Any screen shot?

Comment: Stripe::InvalidRequestError in ChargesController#create

Comment: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once

Comment: How am I supposed to change the codes above??

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. However, this error message means that the card token you're trying to use in your customer creation request (in the `params[:stripeToken]` variable) has already been used.

Stripe tokens can only be used in a single request. Afterwards, the token is consumed and cannot be used again.

You'd have to create a new card token, using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), or directly by using the [create token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) API endpoint.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Ywain. So Could you give some specific examples about what the code should look like?